# What does the return value mean for the UI TextField Delegate method textFieldShouldReturn:?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The apple docs offer:

> Asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the
>   return button.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
> ```
>
> Parameters `textField` The text field whose return button was pressed.
>   `Return Value` `YES` if the text field should implement its default
>   behavior for the return button; otherwise, `NO`.
>
> Discussion The text field callsthis method whenever the user tapsthe
>   return button. You can use this method to implement any custom
>   behavior when the button is tapped.

My question is what does the return value do?  I have been implementing the behavior in this method so it makes no difference what is returned.  Is this not the correct method to perform the action?

For instance, if I implement a search function, should I trigger the search action in this method or somewhere else.

Comment: Yep, you can trigger your search here (or sometimes, people will initiate searches as they type, in which case you don't need to do that here). But, yes, if you wanted to implement your own behavior when the user hits the return key, you'd return NO here and do whatever you thought was appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct method to trigger an action when the user taps the Return keyboard key (whatever it happens to be labeled).

The return value from the `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method almost never matters. If you are dealing with a single text field then it definitely doesn't matter.

I ran into one issue a while back that made me realize that just under the right situation, the return value does matter. I had a screen with several text fields and then a text view. I was using this text field delegate method to change the first responder from text field to text field to text view. I found that if I returned `YES` in this delegate method and then made the text view the first responder, the newline was being sent to the text view.

As a result of this, I now always return `NO` from this delegate method to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

When you press the return button on the keyboard the `textFieldShouldReturn` is called.
I never experienced any difference between the return value.

Customization example:

If you have two textFields when the user presses return button from first textField, you can give focus to second field in the following way:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn:");
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
        UITextField *passwordTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
        [passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**So you can use this delegate method for triggering search functionality.**

Comment: In my experience, returning `YES` has absolutely no effect on the keyboard. In the code you posted, return `NO` will make no difference. It is the call to `resignFirstResponder` that makes the keyboard disappear, not returning `YES`.

Comment: @rmaddy: found the issue with my answer and fixed it.