# What is the default behavior for a UITextField Return Button?

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

I am relatively new to iOS programming, and have been curious about a pretty common UITextField delegate function.

In the developer documentation for `optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` it states:

> Return Value true if the text field should implement its default
>   behavior for the return button; otherwise, false.

I am curious as to what the default behavior for a return button is?  In what cases would I return true, or false?

Comment: Curious why this was reopened. It is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994289/what-does-the-return-value-mean-for-the-ui-textfield-delegate-method-textfieldsh

Comment: I didn’t turn that up in my search. Thanks for linking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the keyboard when the user clicks return button then

```
return true
```

otherwise default is `false` , the logic depends on your UX of whether you want the keyboard visible all time or not

Comment: So anytime you call resignFirstResponder in the text field inside the delegate function, you should return true, and there really isn’t any other default behavior”?

Comment: not necessarily as `textf.resignFirstResponder()/view.endEditing(true)` will hide it anyway

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The return value has no effect on the display of the keyboard.

Comment: That's kind of the source confusion, since (as far as I know) you can't hide the keyboard without calling resignFirstResponder within the delegate function, or by calling endEditing on the view; so it almost seems like the return is pointless?

Comment: See the duplicate I just linked. It is confusing and almost pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy what's exactly is incorrect ?? the keyboard hides only after clicking return button when implementing the method with return true

Comment: The keyboard does not hide using this method. It hides when you call resignFirstResponder or endEditing. Of course you typically call one of them from this delegate but it’s not the delegate or its return value that does the hiding.

Comment: i don't care about the inner implementation of return key in keyboard but it will hide only when return is true , also my comment above clarifies when doing it without clicking return keyboard

Comment: you have a misunderstanding all my answer descibes about return key in keyboard what you said now is what i commented above that anyway return was inside `textFieldShouldReturn` doing `textf.resignFirstResponder()/view.endEditing(true) `  will hide keyboard , read it above

Comment: Really ?? comments are not parts of an answer  what that rude saying ?  the op asks and i commented according to the comment

Comment: @rmaddy and why wouldn't read the comment and say that from the beginning? , is making the answer incorrect something you like so op refuses it ?